# TradingView/PineScript How to use a "fixed" lowest as a stop loss?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm a bit new to Pinescript, maybe I'm asking something dumb.

I'll try to explain clearly :
I open a short position, I use a lowest(close,20) to set my stop loss.
But as long as my trade goes, my stop loss will change for the new lowest(close,20).

Example :
[image: Example]

The blue line is the lowest(close,20), we can see it was around 38880 when the trade was opened (I would like to keep this 38880 for my stop loss, no matter what), but 20 minutes later the new lowest(close,20) is something like 38620 (because it wasn't moving that much) and the stop loss stopped the trade.

I hope you could understand, I'm not fluent.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some of your code. If you calling strategy.exit() on each bar, and if SL values changes, then strategy.exit() function will rewrite its parameters. Probably you need to put calculation of your SL value inside local scope when the entry condition occurs

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to do, right now it's on each bar. I'll try to find a way to do it in a local scope, thank you !